# Wiring a Ceiling-fan and switch while disconnecting an outlet from the switch

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, ceiling-fan

A couple of years ago I replaced a ceiling light in the MB with a ceiling fan/light using a remote control wall switch (light off/on with dimmer; fan off/on, high, med, low).  There is only one switch. This worked great until I plugged the vacuum into the wall outlet nearest the switch,  which was apparently wired to the wall switch. This action immediately fried the wall switch and the bottom half of the outlet ceased working.  Note, it was only the bottom half of the outlet that caused the failure as the top half of the outlet was in use with a clock radio without a problem.

What I now wish to do is:
1)  Put in one wall switch that will turn on/off the power to the fan/light both.
2)  Disconnect the outlet from the wall switch so that the outlet, both top and bottom, are always on and not effected by the switch.
3)  Then I will wire in a fan/light remote control that will work when the wall switch is on but not when it is off.  This part I can do.

The Question:  What is the proper wiring configuration for the switch and the outlet to meet the above conditions?

The Current Wiring Situation:
The Switch:  Three sets of wires, including white and black, white and black, white and black and red.  All having a grounding wire.
The Outlet:  Two sets of wires, including white and black, and white and black and red.  Currently it is wired as such when looking at it as if looking at the BACK of the outlet:  Upper Right (UR) is White, Lower Right (LR) is White, Upper Left (UL) is Black, Lower Left (LL) is Red.  Both sets have a grounding wire.
There are a total of four outlets in the MB.
The Ceiling:  One set of wires which is white and black with grounding wire.

Thanks for your help

Correct, it is a wireless remote @ThreePhaseEel.

Comment: What model of remote control are you using?

Comment: Hmm, not sure how to answer that.  How about a pic? Or can you tell me more specifically what you need to know, as I don't see a brand name.

Comment: A picture helps -- make sure the label on it is readable

Comment: No luck with the pic.  The label:  JY326B(5+6uF)

Comment: Or do you want the schematic label, so small I can't read it, but is included on paper?
AC Power Input:  Black Wire AC in L; White Wire AC in N.
To Fan Motor from Receiver:  
fan/light/neutral White 
Fan/live Black
Light/Live Blue

Comment: I take it the remote's a wireless type?

Comment: Correct, it is a wireless remote.

Comment: How attached are you to the dimming function on it?  Also, are you OK with replacing the remote/receiver with a different one?

Comment: If it can't be done then I'm not attached.  
The instructions for the remote do state not to use it with any rheostat wall control, which is why I wanted to change the wall switch to straight off/on.  Therefore, the dimmer is a function of the wireless control only, not the wall switch.
I have another wall switch just like the one that got fried:  Litex Model# WCI-100.  Same features as the wireless remote but in a wall switch format.
What do you propose?

Comment: The wireless remote I have is exactly the same as this:  Harbor Breeze 43147 Ceiling Fan & Light Remote Control Kit NEW Universal

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is actually very easy to fix based on the information you've given -- simply replace the outlet with a new one without breaking the tab off the hot side, connect the black wire to the hot screw on the outlet, and cap off the red wire at the outlet with a wirenut instead of connecting it to the new outlet.

Comment: OK, that sounds great.  I still don't know how to wire the switch which has three sets of wires as described above.  I'm thinking it must need a double switch like almost all the other bedrooms have: one to control ceiling light, one to control the outlet, except I don't want the outlet controlled by a switch.

Comment: Post photos of the switch box configuration and we can help you with that @F.Hooper